# java.util.date/Calendar/SimpleDateFormat: Adding/Incrementing the months in java

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I have tried the following; but the results are disappointing.
I want to increment the the months.

```
 String dStartTime="2012-03-01";
 SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-DD");
 Date dateStartTime = dateFormatter.parse(dStartTime);
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
 cal.setTime(dateStartTime); 
 cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
 System.out.println(cal.getTime());
 System.out.println(dateFormatter.format(cal.getTime()));
```

**OUTPUT** 
Wed Feb 01 00:00:00 IST 2012  --- This is correct
2012-02-32                    --- This is wrong. I want the Day should be one.

Please let me know what is the problem here?

Comment: You can find all valid pattern characters in the javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-DD")` to `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")`.
`DD` is "Day in year" but you need `dd` "Day in month".
See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html for Date and Time Patterns.